# Odata URL conversion error on "orderby"

Tags: c#, android, odata

I need to show data in orderby

i have url like this and need to show data based on datewise

i tried like this

```
http://localhost:33396/values.svc/Names?$format=json&$expand=Address&$select=Address/PhoneNumber,Address/Pincode&$filter=Address/any(value:value/Pincode+eq+guid%27600045%27)+and+Address/any(value:value/country+eq+guid%27India%27)%20&$orderby=Address/Date+desc
```

but i am getting error like this

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parent value for a property access of a property 'Date' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."}}}
```

how can i solve this

Comment: Does it work if $orderby clause is deleted in the URL?

Comment: yes its working with orderby @TanJinfu

Comment: As for your Uri, it seems that one Name has several Addresses. doesn't that your service supposed to be? I think you actually expect that each Name has only one Address, right?

Comment: No @LaylaLiuMSFT One Name has only one Address

Comment: @mekala, Could you please provide me your $metadata?

Answer (score 0):

The Address is a navigation property on Names right? And from the error shows, I think Address is a collection. Property access can only be used on a single value, or it will get confused by using which of the items to get the specified property "Date" in the "Address" collection.

Comment: It looks like it is the root cause.

Comment: No, Names and Address is different tables i expand Address in url @Junlin Zheng

Comment: Could you provide your service or metadata to me to have a look please?